# Barcode regex help11

Tags: regex

I'm looking to create a regular expression to be used with a document scanning software that uses a code 128 barcode with the following format

Match-CustomerName-CustomerRef

The first part Match will always be the same, however the second and third will vary.

Is this possible?

Also if all three elements of the barcode were to be different each time, could an expression be configure in a simlar way to look for a code 128 barcode?

Comment: Please give some examples

Comment: Hi  stan780953, welcome to Stackoverflow! Questions need to have a [clear problem statement](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you provide a code sample, someone may be able to help you with this. The [Asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is worth a read too. Also what regex engine are you using? The syntax can vary quite a bit.

Comment: There are different charsets for Code 128 (A, B or C). Do you expect a particular charset? What kind of validation are you looking for? Does it have a fixed length? Is it a numeric barcode or FNC4 encoded? Is the barcode in the middle of some text that may be mistaken with a barcode?... There are several ways this can be approached. Would you mind carifying what it is exactly?

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't provide a language or regex implementation you wish to use, here an example written in Python:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

ExampleStrings = [ 'Match-CustomerName-CustomerRef',
                   'Match-blablub!%&-123']

pattern = re.compile(r"Match-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$")

for string in ExampleStrings:
    matches = re.match(pattern, string)
    print matches.group(1)
    print matches.group(2)
```

Output in console:

> CustomerName
>
> CustomerRef
>
> blablub!%&
>
> 123